# Use cross compiler to compile a C++ library with Gradle

Tags: c++, gradle, cross-compiling

I am attempting to cross-compile a C++ library using Gradle and the GCC cross-compiler for arm64 on my machine. However, when I run the compilation, I receive an error message from Gradle stating that none of the toolchains work for aarch64.

build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
plugins {
    `cpp-library`
    `gcc-compiler`
}

library {
    linkage.set(listOf(Linkage.SHARED, Linkage.STATIC))
    targetMachines.set(listOf(
        machines.linux.x86_64,
        machines.linux.x86,
        machines.linux.architecture("arm64")))
}
```

The error is:

```
> Error while evaluating property 'compilerVersion' of task ':compileReleaseSharedArm64Cpp'.
   > No tool chain is available to build C++ for host operating system 'Linux' architecture 'aarch64':
       - Tool chain 'visualCpp' (Visual Studio):
           - Visual Studio is not available on this operating system.
       - Tool chain 'gcc' (GNU GCC):
           - Don't know how to build for host operating system 'Linux' architecture 'aarch64'.
       - Tool chain 'clang' (Clang):
           - Don't know how to build for host operating system 'Linux' architecture 'aarch64'.
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error line?